# Purple screen when working with vertex shaders

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

Alright, so I've tried everything I can think of. I've put in over 10 hours into this crap, but nothing seems to work (tried multiple online tutorials as well). Always purple screen.

Here is the simple .fx code:

```
float4x4 matrixTransform;

struct VShader
{
    float2 Coords : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Position : POSITION;
};
struct PShader
{
    float2 Coords : TEXCOORD0;
};

VShader VertexShaderFunction(VShader input)
{
    VShader output;

    output.Position = mul(input.Position, matrixTransform);
    output.Coords = input.Coords;

    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(PShader input) : COLOR0
{

    return tex2D(textureSampler, input.Coords);
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm assigning `MatrixTransform`:

```
Matrix Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(GameSettings.VectorResolution.X, GameSettings.VectorResolution.Y, -1, 1);

Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
Projection = halfPixelOffset * Projection;

x.Parameters["matrixTransform"].SetValue(camera.Projection);
```

**Note**: the above code works just fine when the vertex shader is *disabled*. Everything displays like normal.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

```
public Matrix World { get; protected set; }
public Matrix Projection { get; protected set; }
public Matrix View(Vector2 parallax)
{
    return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position * parallax, 0.0f)) *
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Origin, 0.0f)) *
        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
        Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom, Zoom, 1) *
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Origin, 0.0f));
}

public void ReloadMatrices()
{
    World = Matrix.Invert(View(Vector2.One));
    Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(GameSettings.VectorResolution.X, GameSettings.VectorResolution.Y, -1, 1);
    Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0f, -0f, 0);
    Projection *= halfPixelOffset;
}
```

Zoom is 1f, Rotation always remains unchanged, and Origin is center of screen.

Comment: I'll bet there's an answer here: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=purple+screen&PageIndex=1

Comment: specifically this one: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/95682/571781.aspx#571781

Comment: Is `camera.Projection` the same as the `Projection` you defined in the line before? Btw, your offset is wrong. It needs to be in clip space and you should multiply it to the right of `Projection`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, yes, it is! I just changed the `Projection` line to be `Projection *= halfPixelOffset`. Also, I'm not entirely certain what is meant by "clip space". How can I do this?